# SQL Group and Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, group-by

In SQL Server 2008, I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID |  RefNum   |  Label        |   Value  |  Status
------------------------------------------------------
1       123      OrderNum         123456       0
2       123      TrackingNum      111111       0
3       123      ConfNum          989898       0
4       234      OrderNum         234567       1
5       234      TrackingNum      222222       1
6       234      ConfNum          878787       0
7       567      OrderNum         345678       1
8       567      TrackingNum      333333       0
9       567      ConfNum          767676       0
```

I want to select all records where Status = 0 and join, based on RefNum, to the 'OrderNum'  and 'TrackingNum' Label values, regardless of whether 'OrderNum' and TrackingNum Statuses are 1 or 0.  For example, the query should produce:

```
ID |  RefNum   |  Label        |   Value  | Status |OrderNum|TrackingNum
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       123      OrderNum         123456       0    123456   111111
2       123      TrackingNum      111111       0    123456   111111
3       123      ConfNum          989898       0    123456   111111
6       234      ConfNum          878787       0    234567   222222
8       567      TrackingNum      333333       0    345678   333333
9       567      ConfNum          767676       0    345678   333333
```

Right now, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT                  Id
               ,mT.RefNum
               ,Label
               ,Value
               ,Status
               ,OrderNum
               ,TrackingNum
FROM [dbo].[myTable] AS mT
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) As OrderRowId, RefNum, Value AS OrderNum
    FROM [dbo].[myTable]
    WHERE Label= 'OrderNum'
    group by RefNum, Value) AS OrderNums
    ON OrderNums.RefNum= mt.RefNum
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(ID) As OrderRowId, RefNum, Value AS TrackingNum
    FROM [dbo].[myTable]
    WHERE Label= 'TrackingNum'
    group by RefNum, Value) AS TrackingNums
    ON TrackingNums.RefNum= mt.RefNum
WHERE ProcessComplete = 0
```

This apprears to work, but requires a hash join.  Would love someone to shoot holes in this or provide a more efficient solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Hash join's are efficient.  What is the problem?  By the way, why not just reduce each `RefNum` to one row with the three items of information on the row?  That seems like a sensible result for this type of data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You make great points.  In the grand scheme, it's not a big deal to have a hash join.  I'm just wondering if it can get better.  The real problem is that I have about 25 different labels and they aren't always guaranteed to be there.  I could group by each label and refnum, but grouping and consequentially converting the output like that is a little too invasive right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there can't be duplicate order numbers or tracking numbers per reference number, you can simplify the query somewhat with a regular `LEFT JOIN` or `JOIN`;

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.refnum, mt.label, mt.value, mt.status,
       ordno.value ordernum, trackno.value trackingnum
FROM myTable mt
LEFT JOIN myTable ordno
  ON ordno.label='ordernum' and mt.refnum=ordno.refnum
LEFT JOIN myTable trackno
  ON trackno.label='trackingnum' and mt.refnum=trackno.refnum
WHERE mt.status = 0;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e28ca/4).

If there may be duplicates, you can still do a single `GROUP BY` to get a result;

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.refnum, mt.label, mt.value, mt.status,
       MAX(ordno.value) ordernum, MAX(trackno.value) trackingnum
FROM myTable mt
LEFT JOIN myTable ordno
  ON ordno.label='ordernum' and mt.refnum=ordno.refnum
LEFT JOIN myTable trackno
  ON trackno.label='trackingnum' and mt.refnum=trackno.refnum
WHERE mt.status = 0
GROUP BY mt.id,mt.refnum,mt.label,mt.value,mt.status;
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2e11/1).

Comment: This seems to use a nested loop whereas the inner join uses a hash match.

Comment: An inner join like yours will make the plan more efficient, if you're sure that tracking# and order# always exist. Also, I did not include any indexes in the SQLfiddle, since it's hard to optimize for 10 rows of data in a useful way :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand :)  Those two values will always exist.  I'm wondering if maybe something like a CTE would be more efficient.  Anything else other than this specific approach.